# Slow Serializion process Django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, python-requests

Im using django_rest_framework for my project and i have a problem.

#### models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class RelatedField3_2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RelatedField3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    relfield3_2 = models.ForeignKey(RelatedField3_2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RelatedField2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RelatedField1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MainTable(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
    field3 = models.IntegerField()
    field4 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)
    field5 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    field6 = models.IntegerField()
    relfield1 = models.ForeignKey(RelatedField1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    relfield2 = models.ForeignKey(RelatedField2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    relfield3 = models.ForeignKey(RelatedField3, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#### serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from main.models import MainTable, RelatedField1, RelatedField2, RelatedField3


class MainTableRelatedFields(serializers.RelatedField):
    def display_value(self, instance):
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return self.queryset.model.objects.get(name=data)


class MainTableSerializerList(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        records = [MainTable(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return self.child.Meta.model.objects.bulk_create(records)


class MainTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MainTable
        list_serializer_class = MainTableSerializerList

    id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=False, required=False)
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    relfield3 = PartnerPropRelatedFields(queryset=RelatedField3.objects.all())
    relfield2 = PartnerPropRelatedFields(queryset=RelatedField2.objects.all())
    relfield1 = PartnerPropRelatedFields(queryset=RelatedField1.objects.all())

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

#### views.py:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from .serializers import MainTableSerializer


class MainTableUploadView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @action(['post'], detail=False)
    def upload_records(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        seriazlizer = MainTableSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        seriazlizer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        seriazlizer.save(owner=request.user)
        return Response(seriazlizer.data)
```

#### send_json.py:

```
import requests

data_load_list = [{    
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": 2,
        "field3": 3,
        "field4": "field4",
        "field5": 5,
        "field6": "field6",
        "relfield1": "test1",
        "relfield2": "test2",
        "relfield3" : "test3"
    } for i in range(1000)
]

load_list_response = requests.post(url=url_upload, headers={'Authorization': f'Token {TOKEN}'}, 
                                   json=data_load_list)
```

When i start send_json.py for sending **1000** records, i just get error:

```
RemoteDisconnected                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    425                     # Otherwise it looks like a bug in the code.
--> 426                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    427         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    420                 try:
--> 421                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    422                 except BaseException as e:

/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1331             try:
-> 1332                 response.begin()
   1333             except ConnectionError:

/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in begin(self)
    302         while True:
--> 303             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    304             if status != CONTINUE:

/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    271             # sending a valid response.
--> 272             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    273                                      " response")

RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    725 
--> 726             retries = retries.increment(
    727                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    402             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 403                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    404             elif read is not None:

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    733             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 734                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    735             raise value

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    425                     # Otherwise it looks like a bug in the code.
--> 426                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    427         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    420                 try:
--> 421                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    422                 except BaseException as e:

/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1331             try:
-> 1332                 response.begin()
   1333             except ConnectionError:

/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in begin(self)
    302         while True:
--> 303             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    304             if status != CONTINUE:

/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    271             # sending a valid response.
--> 272             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    273                                      " response")

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    117     """
    118 
--> 119     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    120 
    121 

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    528         }
    529         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 530         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    531 
    532         return resp

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    641 
    642         # Send the request
--> 643         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/DKykH6t1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    496 
    497         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 498             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    499 
    500         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

When i start send_json.py for sending **100** records, the data is loaded into the database and returned with a code 200. This takes *15 seconds*.

How and with what can I optimize my code so that I can send 1000+ records to the database and get information in the response body quickly?

Comment: does your request terminate immediately or after some time? also show us the log on the server's side.

Comment: The request terminate after a while (10-20 seconds of waiting). The server-side logs do not display any information on such a request.

Comment: @AviKKi Can I get alternative logs from somewhere, or make such requests be logged?

Comment: This is probably a client timeout, try to set a bigger timeout `requests.post(url=url_upload, headers={'Authorization': f'Token {TOKEN}'},json=data_load_list, timeout=3600)`, adding these many entries to DB takes time it is normal. I'll answer with some optimization techniques later. PS: Do you want to load a ton of data in your Django DB? you shouldn't send that over an request, rather use a custom management command. let me know your use case, I'll drop you some useful code snippet.

Comment: @AviKKi Thanks for the recommendations.
It did not help to increase the timeout in the request on the client side, the request is still interrupted with the same error after 10-20 seconds. And yes, my goal is to load a large amount of data to the server precisely through the **post request**, while receiving in the response not the ids of the associated fields, but their names

Comment: The server logs would really help, as we don't know why the connection was closed, try increasing request size (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size), or if you have any server side timeout. If this doesn't work alternate approach would be to upload a .json file to the server and process it through celery workers in background, return client a token in first request, then client can check by that token for results in some regular interval of time.

Comment: @AviKKI Server side history doesn't really display information about a large data load request.
For example, if I run my send_json.py script to send 100 entries, it completes in 15 seconds and I see an entry in the django logs about this request. If I run the same script to send 250+ records, this request just fail and does not appear in the logs

Comment: will the method with `celery workers` work for you? If you can upload a file, it's achievable that way.

Comment: using celery is not suitable for my task, if only because other people will use my api

Comment: can you create a repository with minimum reproducible code, it would be much easier to debug for people here.

Comment: @AviKKi You can find it here: https://github.com/hax2000/Relaed-Fields-API
Important note: for my purpose the django server must be remote and not local

Comment: @AviKKi Don't have any optimization recommendations yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution that helped me (see changes in pull request):

https://github.com/hax2000/Relaed-Fields-API/pull/1/files